# mouseOver do not works in IE for selenium RC

Tags: selenium

I am trying to do mouse over an element in `IE9 browser`. After mouse
hover a toll tip will open. To do this I am using:

```
selenium.mouseOver("css=a.worldwide");
```

It works fine, in `FF browser`. But fails in `IE browser`. I am using:
`Selenium RC 2.18.0`. I have also try this by both Xpath and `CSS`
locator. But it fails.

Can any body please help me how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem (with IE 9 only). It works on IE 7 & 8, FF 3.6 & 11, Opera 11, Safari 5 and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not answer to your question but may help you.

`getAttribute("css=a.worldwide@title")); // getAttribute(locator@attribute name)`

This function will return the text available for title attribute for the element specified.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript/jQuery I managed to work around the problem:

```
selenium.eval('selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery("a.worldwide").trigger("mouseover");')
```

I'm using python, so you may need to adjust quotes.

I have no idea what jQuery does that selenium doesn't, but this made the problem go away for me on Saucelabs & Selenium 1.